# how to unistall kerberos on CentOS

Tags: centos, kerberos, uninstallation

I am experimenting with Kerberos and messed up the installation. When I make it ,there are too many config in default dictionaries. I've tried many different ways to uninstall it clean but failed like this:

[root@kdc1 krb5-1.9]# cd src/
[root@kdc1 src]# make uninstall
make: *** No rule to make target `uninstall'.  Stop.

so ,how can I uninstall Kerberos?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you need to delete packages you installed for kerberos(version 5 we're talking about)

- yum remove krb5-server
- yum remove krb5-libs
- yum remove krb5-workstation

This won't remove the folders. You have to remove them manually. So

1. rm -rf /var/kerberos/
2. rm /etc/krb5.conf
3. rm -rf /usr/lib64/krb5

And you can install the packages again.

**Note:** I came here looking for the answer to the same question you asked. However, I have solved this issue and I'd like to tell the solution to this problem. Perhaps, I'm late but for the future, it may help others.

Comment: I deleted the file rm /etc/krb5.conf as instructed but after I reinstalled, and tried to configure it again but it now shows up as empty. I thought it would just reinstall the default config file as well but I guess not?

Comment: When i tried "yum remove krb5-libs" it said "Error: Trying to remove "systemd", which is protected" and "Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected". Are you sure your guide won't destroy my production node?